# wpf привязка конкретной фигуры к конкретному элементу коллекции

Tags: c#, wpf

Во  вьюмодели коллекция из четырех моделей. В представлении четыре линии. 
Как менять цвет линии в зависимости от выбранной модели ? Если выбрали первую модель, то цвет первой линии меняется с синего на красный. Выбрана вторая модель --
вторая линия становится красной, первая опять синей. 
Добавлено: пока для простоты количество линий зависит от количества элементов Models

код

```
   public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            private string name;


            public string Name
            {
                get { return name; }
                set
                {
                    name = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Name");
                }
            }


            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            public void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
            }
        }
```

```
 public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Model selectedModel;

        public ObservableCollection<Model> Models { get; set; }
        public Model SelectedModel
        {
            get { return selectedModel; }
            set
            {
                selectedModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedModel");
            }
        }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            Models = new ObservableCollection<Model>
            {
                new Model { Name="A" },
                new Model {Name="B", },
                new Model {Name="C" },
                new Model {Name="D" }
            };
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
```

разметка

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ListBox
            Grid.Column="0"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Models}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedModel}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="5">
                        <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{Binding SelectedModel}">
            <TextBlock Text="Выбранный элемент" />
            <TextBlock Text="Модель" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

        </StackPanel>
        <Canvas Grid.Column="2">
            <Line
                Canvas.Left="10"
                Canvas.Top="20"
                Stroke="Red"
                X1="0"
                X2="100"
                Y1="0"
                Y2="00" />
            <Line
                Canvas.Left="10"
                Canvas.Top="40"
                Stroke="Blue"
                X1="0"
                X2="100"
                Y1="0"
                Y2="00" />
            <Line
                Canvas.Left="10"
                Canvas.Top="60"
                Stroke="Blue"
                X1="0"
                X2="100"
                Y1="0"
                Y2="00" />
            <Line
                Canvas.Left="10"
                Canvas.Top="80"
                Stroke="Blue"
                X1="0"
                X2="100"
                Y1="0"
                Y2="00" />

        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: вроде  простой вопрос. не знаю что  правильно искать

Comment: А количество линий зависит от количества элементов Models?

Comment: Создавайте линии с помощью ItemsControl, а не вручную. Цвет устанавливайте триггером. Возможно потребуется конвертер, для того чтобы сравнить текущий элемент с выделенным.

Comment: @АндрейNOP спасибо

Comment: @Sublihim пока пусть количество линий зависит от количества элементов Models, дальше будет сложнее

Comment: @Question1 тогда следует поступить, как советует АндрейNOP